# Problems scraping specific content from a DIV - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping this [URL](http://www.accorhotels.com/gb/hotel-5548-mercure-niederbronn-hotel/restaurant.shtml)

I want to scrape all of restaurants like so that I get restaurant name Type of cuisine and opening hours in  separate variable but I am not sure how to iterate over them

You can see from link that restaurant `RESTAURANT DU CASINO IVORY` and `LA STUB DU CASINO` are in the same div `div.infos-restos` so that is why I am iterating over `h3`s and then getting the next_siblings in to get `Type of cuisine`

Here is my code

```
for rests in dining_soup.select("div.infos-restos"):

        for rest in rests.select("h3"):
            print("            Rest Name: "+rest.text)
            print(rest.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.string)
```

Another question :) : Line `print(rest.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.string)` prints the full HTML. How do get the Text only?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)

beautifulsoup dose not support `xpath`
In my opinion its much more simpler to extract data from DOM with `xpath`

here is how you do it:

```
from lxml import etree
import requests

url = 'http://www.accorhotels.com/gb/hotel-5548-mercure-niederbronn-hotel/restaurant.shtml'
res = requests.get(url)

tree = etree.HTML(res.content)  
rest_name_xpath = '//div[@class="infos-restos"]/div[@class="detail-resto"]/following-sibling::h3'

for item in tree.xpath(rest_name_xpath):
    print item.text
```

output:

```
RESTAURANT DU CASINO IVORY
BAR DES MACHINES A SOUS
```

ps:
 the html of this site is badly written and has no proper stracture. that's why the `xpath` is long and ugly

Comment: upvote for `the html of this site is badly written` .. I have the same feeling